# Result output varied in date time query

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, date, datetime

i have a query which is generated from dotnet program where i am passing date  in SearchString parameter as follows

```
 Public Function Getdata(ByVal d As Date) As DataTable 

WHERE (IC.ICD_UPDATE_DT IS NULL OR IC.ICD_UPDATE_DT > :SearchString and IC.Icd_Create_Dt < SearchString))
cmdCR.Parameters.AddWithValue(":SearchString", d.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

it results no rows 39

while i am checking it at query side manually as below it results only 30 rows as follows

```
 WHERE (IC.ICD_UPDATE_DT IS NULL OR trunc(IC.ICD_UPDATE_DT) > '30-nov-2020' )
         and trunc(IC.Icd_Create_Dt) < '30-nov-2020' )
```

so i am not able to find why is there different output for same condition. Any  idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question

Comment: @00110001 i have just posted  where condition part how i have written in dotnet program and then the value coming in SearchString parameter , i took it and modified sqlquery for same condition and then generate output. but reults differ

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 trunc() in the where below and missing in the query above.

Using trunc() against a date cuts off the time and makes dates like '01.12.2021 01:23:34' to look like '01.12.2021 00:00:00'.

Thus, lines having icd_create_dt = '30-nov-2020 13:24' will be in the output of the first query and be shown in your test query

Comment: no i am just use trunc manually at  plsql to see the output ,since no  any other idea how to check in plsql. so i use  trunc(IC.ICD_UPDATE_DT) > '30-nov-2020'

Answer (score 0):

Trying with this format in sql query solve my issue

```
WHERE (trunc(IC.ICD_UPDATE_DT) IS NULL OR to_date(IC.ICD_UPDATE_DT,'DD/MM/YYYY') > '30-nov-2020' )
         and to_date(IC.Icd_Create_Dt,'DD/MM/YYYY') < '30-nov-2020' )
```